# boolean operators evaluation order

Tags: javascript

I've this piece of code and I can't figure out the execution order:

```
var enabled = item.get_property('Quantity') > 0 && item.get_property('UnitPrice') > 0 || item.get_id() === null
```

Mozilla states [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) that `&&` operator has higher precendence that `||`, so I'd expect something like that:

1. Is `item.get_property('Quantity') > 0` true? If yes, move forward
2. Is `item.get_property('UnitPrice') > 0` true? If yes, move forward
3. Is `item.get_id() === null` true? If yes, return yes

But obviously it's not the way it works. It returns 'true' if `item.get_id() === null` equals to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an expression like a x b y c, x and y being operators, x having higher precedence means that the expression is equivalent to ((a x b) y c). As you can see, if you substitute && for x and || for y, the intrepreter will evaluate a && b, meaning if a is false it will shortcut to false, but if it is true it will check the boolean value of b. If (a && b) is true, then the interpreter will shortcut to true, but if not, will check c and return true only if it evaluates to true.

The following table summarizes all the possible scenarios:

```
a    b    c    Evaluates    Result
0    0    0    a,c          0
0    0    1    a,c          1
0    1    0    a,c          0
0    1    1    a,c          1
1    0    0    a,b,c        0
1    0    1    a,b,c        1
1    1    0    a,b          1
1    1    1    a,b          1
```

Answer (score 2):

It works exactly the way it says.

Higher precedence means that the operator is evaluated first. JavaScript will short circuit whenever possible.

You should read the expression like this (apply parantheses to operators of highest precedence first):

```
var enabled = (item.get_property('Quantity') > 0 && item.get_property('UnitPrice') > 0) 
              || item.get_id() === null
```

Regarding the execution order, I don't think you can say anything in general about whether item.get_property() will be evaluated before item.get_id(), as this most likely depends on the javascript engine implementation. Some implementations would probably evaluate `item.get_id() === null` first, as this requires "less work" in the sense that there are fewer method calls, but the operator precedence should be respected regardless of the execution order.

Comment: Most interpreters/compilers will also short circuit logical expressions, so you could a premature exit of your expression without complete evaluation -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

Comment: You say it evaluates both expressions either side of the `&&`. This only happens if the first one is true. Also it is not implementation dependent. Guaranteed [left to right](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)

Comment: Yes, you're both absolutely right - I will try to rephrase my answer to elaborate a little more on the short circuiting.